# django call .annotate context processors in DetailView

Tags: django, django-templates, annotations, foreign-keys, counter

My project depending on giving users points for any thing they do (post, comment, like, favourite, ....)

i created context processor to use some calculations inside several templates.

My problem is i cannot call these context processors inside template without for loop

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite', blank=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='commenter')
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')

class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
```

**views.py**

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'user/user-details.html'
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
            User, username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
        )
```

**settings.py**

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'common.context_processors.user_counters',
            ],
```

**templates.html**

```
<ul class="dynamic-tabs-list">
    <li data-content=".content-points">Points
        <span class="badge badge-light">{{ user.total_score }}</span></li>
</ul>
```

**context_processors.py**

```
def user_counters(request):
        user_qs = User.objects\
            .annotate(
                user_posts_count=Count('posts', distinct=True),
                user_posts_score=F('user_posts_count') * 10,)\
            .annotate(
                user_comments_count=Count('commenter', distinct=True),
                user_comments_score=F('user_comments_count') * 10,)\
            .annotate(
                user_favourites_count=Count('favourite', distinct=True),
                user_favourite_score=F('user_favourites_count') * 10,) \
            .annotate(
                user_likes_count=Count('likes', distinct=True),
                user_likes_score=F('user_likes_count') * 10, ) \
            .annotate(
                total_score=F('user_posts_score')+F('user_comments_score')+F('user_favourite_score')+F('user_likes_score')
                    )
        context = {
            'user_qs': user_qs,
        }
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
path('profile/<username>/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
```

Any help please ?

Thanks in-advance

Answer (score 0):

In your function user_counters, User objects is not taking a single object, instead it takes the whole users, in which you have to use for loop.

I would suggest passing that function to the DetailView:

Instead of

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
template_name = 'user/user-details.html'
queryset = User.objects.all()

def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(
        User, username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
    )
```

Change it to :

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
   template_name = 'user/user-details.html'
   queryset = User.objects.all()

   def get_object(self):
       user_detail = get_object_or_404(
        User, username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
       )

       return user_counters(user_detail)
```

And context_processors.py

```
def user_counters(user):
    user_qs = User.objects.get(username=user)
        .annotate(
            user_posts_count=Count('posts', distinct=True),
            user_posts_score=F('user_posts_count') * 10,)
        .annotate(
            user_comments_count=Count('commenter', distinct=True),
            user_comments_score=F('user_comments_count') * 10,)
        .annotate(
            user_favourites_count=Count('favourite', distinct=True),
            user_favourite_score=F('user_favourites_count') * 10,)
        .annotate(
            user_likes_count=Count('likes', distinct=True),
            user_likes_score=F('user_likes_count') * 10, )
        .annotate(
      total_score=F('user_posts_score')+F('user_comments_score')+F('user_favourite_score')+F('user_likes_score')
                )
    context = {
        'user_qs': user_qs,
    }
    return context
```

Try this, and let me know if it works.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't worked also .. thanks anyway

Comment: @MohamedAbbase try to print user_counters(user_detail) and see what it gets you?

Comment: it is printing `{'user_qs': <QuerySet [<User: Fareed>]>}` .. which is the user i am showing his profile

Comment: good you are getting something, if queryset it means still you need loop, but you want the object itself so just  modify return to >>  return user_counters(user_detail).values()